# Sql variable table name in sp error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create update procedure and I get the following error;

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_name, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 9]
Incorrect syntax near 'update '.

How can write proper procedure please help me? 
I can not solve the problem
My procedure as follows;

```
@tablo nvarchar(100),
@kayit nvarchar(50),
@inceleme nvarchar(50),
@icevap nvarchar(50),
@tespit nvarchar(MAX),
@scevap nvarchar(MAX),
@aksiyon nvarchar(50),
@mutalaa nvarchar(MAX),
@tamamlanma nvarchar(100),
@not nvarchar(MAX),
@izleme nvarchar(50),
@kaydeden nvarchar(50),
@idd int,
@kullanici nvarchar(50),
@yil int,
@donem int

as

DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'select ID into #a from ' + @tablo + 
       ' where yil='+ cast(@yil as varchar(100)) +' and donem='+ cast(@donem     
 as varchar(100)) +' and (ilkkaydeden is null or ilkkaydeden='') and 
 (kull='+ cast(@kullanici as varchar(100)) +' or kull1='+  
 cast(@kullanici as varchar(100)) +' or kull2='+  cast(@kullanici 
  as varchar(100)) +')'
  exec(@sql)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #a WHERE ID=@idd) BEGIN
'update '+@tablo+'

set
kayitzamani='+@kayit+',
incelendimi='+@inceleme+',
cevap='+@icevap+',
ites='+@tespit+',
icevabi='+@scevap+',
iaksiyon='+@aksiyon+',
ison='+@mutalaa+',
ieksiklik='+@tamamlanma+',
inotlar='+@not+',
izleme='+@izleme+',
ilkkaydeden='+@kaydeden+'
 where
ID='+@idd

 END
ELSE BEGIN 
'update '+@tablo+'
set
kayitzamani='+@kayit+',
incelendimi='+@inceleme+',
cevap='+@icevap+',
ites='+@tespit+',
icevabi='+@scevap+',
iaksiyon='+@aksiyon+',
ison='+@mutalaa+',
ieksiklik='+@tamamlanma+',
inotlar='+@not+',
izleme='+@izleme+',
sonkaydeden='+@kaydeden+'
where
ID='+@idd
 END; 

go
```

Comment: Print out the syntax using PRINT, you will then be able to see what it is trying to do and it'll be a lot clearer.

Comment: Don't, just don't write your code like that. It's a open hole for SQL Injection.

Comment: That's exactly what a SQL Injection attack looks like. It may not be malicious code that gets injected, it may be a conversion error, or a syntax error. All are due to the same bug - creating dynamic SQL statements instead of a simple UPDATE

Comment: What are you trying to do with this stored procedure ?  It seems to be trying to do an `UPDATE FROM `. The way it's written you get *none* of the benefits of stored procedures (no speed, security, or plan caching) and *all* of the problems of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the next text:-

```
'update '+@tablo+'

set
kayitzamani='+@kayit+',
incelendimi='+@inceleme+',
cevap='+@icevap+',
ites='+@tespit+',
icevabi='+@scevap+',
iaksiyon='+@aksiyon+',
ison='+@mutalaa+',
ieksiklik='+@tamamlanma+',
inotlar='+@not+',
izleme='+@izleme+',
ilkkaydeden='+@kaydeden+'
 where
ID='+@idd
```

to variable

as next

```
SET @sql ='update '+@tablo+'

set
kayitzamani='+@kayit+',
incelendimi='+@inceleme+',
cevap='+@icevap+',
ites='+@tespit+',
icevabi='+@scevap+',
iaksiyon='+@aksiyon+',
ison='+@mutalaa+',
ieksiklik='+@tamamlanma+',
inotlar='+@not+',
izleme='+@izleme+',
ilkkaydeden='+@kaydeden+'
 where
ID='+@idd
```

Then add the next line:-

```
exec(@sql)
```

**Complete Code:-**

```
@tablo nvarchar(100),
@kayit nvarchar(50),
@inceleme nvarchar(50),
@icevap nvarchar(50),
@tespit nvarchar(MAX),
@scevap nvarchar(MAX),
@aksiyon nvarchar(50),
@mutalaa nvarchar(MAX),
@tamamlanma nvarchar(100),
@not nvarchar(MAX),
@izleme nvarchar(50),
@kaydeden nvarchar(50),
@idd int,
@kullanici nvarchar(50),
@yil int,
@donem int

as

DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'select ID into #a from ' + @tablo + 
       ' where yil='+ cast(@yil as varchar(100)) +' and donem='+ cast(@donem     
 as varchar(100)) +' and (ilkkaydeden is null or ilkkaydeden='') and 
 (kull='+ cast(@kullanici as varchar(100)) +' or kull1='+  
 cast(@kullanici as varchar(100)) +' or kull2='+  cast(@kullanici 
  as varchar(100)) +')'
  exec(@sql)

SET @sql = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #a WHERE ID=@idd) BEGIN' + 
'update '+@tablo+'

set
kayitzamani='+@kayit+',
incelendimi='+@inceleme+',
cevap='+@icevap+',
ites='+@tespit+',
icevabi='+@scevap+',
iaksiyon='+@aksiyon+',
ison='+@mutalaa+',
ieksiklik='+@tamamlanma+',
inotlar='+@not+',
izleme='+@izleme+',
ilkkaydeden='+@kaydeden+'
 where
ID='+ cast(@idd as varchar(100))

 + 'END
ELSE 
BEGIN ' + 
'update '+@tablo+'
set
kayitzamani='+@kayit+',
incelendimi='+@inceleme+',
cevap='+@icevap+',
ites='+@tespit+',
icevabi='+@scevap+',
iaksiyon='+@aksiyon+',
ison='+@mutalaa+',
ieksiklik='+@tamamlanma+',
inotlar='+@not+',
izleme='+@izleme+',
sonkaydeden='+@kaydeden+'
where
ID='+cast(@idd as varchar(100)) + 
 'END; '
 exec(@sql) -- Added
go
```

Comment: I get this error --->Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') and (kull=trp or kull1=trp or kull2=trp)'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ') and (kull=trp or kull1=trp or kull2=trp)'. Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure inceleme_update, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 3] Invalid object name '#a'.

Comment: The Complete Code section is updated, waiting ur feedback.

Comment: I got this error--> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') and 
 (kull=tpuser or kull1=tpuser or kull2=tpuser )'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ') and 
 (kull=tpuser or kull1=tpuser or kull2=tpuser )'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@idd".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near '13'.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3Nnu5ct4PkV09tNjAyaTFwUEU/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3Nnu5ct4PkV09tNjAyaTFwUEU/view?usp=drivesdk @ahmed abdelqader

Comment: It is working fine with me ! .. when exactly getting this error while creating/altering procedure or while executing it ?

Comment: while executing  @ahmed abdelqader

Comment: So where is the code of executing, you provide us with creating only !

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @a TABLE (
    ID int
)

SET @sql = 'select ID from ' + @tablo + 
   ' where yil=@yil and donem=@donem  and (ilkkaydeden is null or ilkkaydeden='') and (kull=@kullanici or kull1=@kullanici or kull2=@kullanici )'
INSERT INTO @a
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@kullanici nvarchar(50),   
    @yil int,
    @donem int,
    @Count int output',
    @kullanici,
    @yil,
    @donem,
    @Count output


IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @a WHERE ID=@idd) 
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'update '+@tablo+'

    set
    kayitzamani=@kayit,
    incelendimi=@inceleme,
    cevap=@icevap,
    ites=tespit,
    icevabi=@scevap,
    iaksiyon=@aksiyon,
    ison=@mutalaa,
    ieksiklik=@tamamlanma,
    inotlar=@not,
    izleme=@izleme,
    ilkkaydeden=@kaydeden
     where
    ID=@idd'
END
...
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@kayit nvarchar(50),
    @inceleme nvarchar(50),
    @icevap nvarchar(50),
    @tespit nvarchar(MAX),
    @scevap nvarchar(MAX),
    @aksiyon nvarchar(50),
    @mutalaa nvarchar(MAX),
    @tamamlanma nvarchar(100),
    @not nvarchar(MAX),
    @izleme nvarchar(50),
    @kaydeden nvarchar(50),
    @idd int',
    @kayit,
    @inceleme,
    @icevap,
    @tespit,
    @scevap,
    @aksiyon,
    @mutalaa,
    @tamamlanma,
    @not,
    @izleme,
    @kaydeden,
    @idd
```

Comment: I am getting same error Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') and (kull=trp or kull1=trp or kull2=trp)'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ') and (kull=trp or kull1=trp or kull2=trp)'. Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure inceleme_update, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 3] Invalid object name '#a'.

Comment: @ismailAlgün, I edited my answer and include your select query

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem fortunately. I added this string to some code izleme=' +''''+@izleme+''''+',

Thank you for everybody